# Embed Mapbox Swiping Maps on HTML

Tags: html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to embed a sliding map onto an HTML page. Right now the map would float on top of other elements. What should I do to make the map appear inside one of the containers?

I try to delete the line .map{position: absolute} but then the map stops showing up at all. I have also tried to make sure other CSS files linked in the HTML is not overriding the map's style.

```
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.mySlides {display: none}

.map {
/*position: absolute;
top: 500px;
bottom: 0;*/
width: 80%;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

body * {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-center w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px" id="band">
    <h2 class="w3-wide">Guangzhou</h2>
    <p class="w3-opacity"><i></i></p>
    <hr>
    <div id='slidemap-cont'>
      <div id='before' class='map'></div>
      <div id='after' class='map'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
var beforeMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'before',
style: 'mapbox://styles/estella213439/cju7drf1x1zr41flvd51t9adb',
center: [113.33833,23.08506],
zoom: 12
});

var afterMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'after',
style: 'mapbox://styles/estella213439/cju7af6q42ia21fqbv7ffas1g',
center: [113.33833,23.08506],
zoom: 12
});

var map = new mapboxgl.Compare(beforeMap, afterMap, {
// Set this to enable comparing two maps by mouse movement:
// mousemove: true
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want the maps to be side-by-side or vertically stacked?

Comment: When you say "swiping map" are you trying to compare two different maps/map styles? The way that it's done in this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-compare/? Or do you have a different goal in mind?

Comment: Yes I mean comparing the two map. I have trouble fitting a slide map I made in a div in an html because it seems it doesn't know to handle two map sharing the same div....

Answer (score 0):

If you need them to both be `position: absolute;`, then you need to specify the `top` for your second element to be the same as the height of the first one

```
.map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}

#before {
  top: 0;
}

#after {
  top: 50%; // Must match height of before element
  padding-top:5px; //So you can see where one map stops and the other begins.
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmyvap7j/3/) with your example to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you for replying!

Comment: I already have the code of a slide map from this tutorial(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-compare/). My main issue is that I can't fit the two maps into a defined div without separating them...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't fit the two maps into a defined div without separating them"? Why is it a requirement to include them in the same `div`? The "slide" effect is accomplished by dynamically modifying either `<div>`s width to give the impression of sliding, so housing each map object in a separate `<div>` element is a pretty significant requirement.